# How to call the DateTimePicker from a textbox in UserForm

Tags: vba, excel, datetimepicker

I have created a TextBox1 within my UserForm.
I have create a Sub called

`Sub TextBox1_Enter()
End Sub`

where by clicking the textbox I want to open the DateTimePicker control to choose a date, and after the date is chosen the chosen date should be the TextBox1.Value

I have the DateTimePicker from mscomct2.ocx

I really don't figure out how to call the control; any tips with code and a good explanation anyone?

Comment: Either add it to your main form and show/hide it as needs be, or add it to another form, and show/hide that. For the other form you'll want a public textbox variable (or a property) that you can set so that it can populate the correct control.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for but you could take a look as [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yQw73kRgkGI). It is very well explained.

Comment: Sorry, with this I need to create more forms to display the calendar view. I should be able to just call the control from the vba code...

Answer (score 0):

My goal was to have an empty DatePicker at form startup, and was told to use a textbox to load the DTPicker upon clicking.

But I found this solution that keep the DTPicker Value empty as form startup

`Private Sub DTPicker1_CloseUp()
  FormatDTPicker
End Sub
Private Sub DTPicker1_Format(ByVal CallbackField As String, FormattedString As String)
  If CallbackField = "X" Then FormattedString = ""
End Sub
Private Sub DTPicker1_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal_
x As stdole.OLE_XPOS_PIXELS, ByValy As stdole.OLE_YPOS_PIXELS)
  With DTPicker1
    If .Value = vbNull Then
      .Value = Now
    End If
  End With
End Sub
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
  DTPicker1.Value = vbNull
  FormatDTPicker
End Sub
Private Sub FormatDTPicker()
  With DTPicker1
    If .Value = vbNull Then
      .Format = dtpCustom
      .CustomFormat = "X"
    Else
      .Format = dtpShortDate
    End If
  End With
End Sub`

http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/666685-dtpicker-value-null.html